# How to create popup box on header and when click on close button then not display in the site using jquery or php?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I want to create functionality using `jquery`, `PHP` or `Javascript`:

> When website is loaded then display popupbox on the header with close
>   button, when click on close button then popup is closed. If not click
>   on close button then that popup is display in all the pages in the
>   website.

Could you please give me suggestion for that? I have no idea about it.

Comment: I have tried using session but no more idea about it..Need full script

Answer (score 0):

Something like [`fancybox`](http://fancybox.net/home)? U may use this [`guide`](http://fancybox.net/howto).

**EDIT**:

try this as per the link u gave
In your php page place this.

```
<?php session_start();?>
<html>
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
//jquery code
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#close_popup').click(function(){
$('#header').css('display','none');
$.post("test.php");
});
})
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="header" style="width:100%;top:0;<?php if(isset($_SESSION['isHeaderClosed']) && $_SESSION['isHeaderClosed'] == true) echo 'display:none;'; ?>">
content <input type="button" id="close_popup"/>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

(in all your pages place session_start(), the div header and the jquery code).

In a new page test.php

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['isHeaderClosed']=true;
?>
```

Comment: No not like fancybox...see this link for the idea.

Comment: ya i tired it but not working..when click on button then button is not closed...pls give me another idea..

Comment: did you add jquery reference.?

Comment: This new edit worked for me. Now use the exact code and then try.. Place the first code block in your pages.. second code block in a new page test.php in the same folder.

Answer (score 0):

Try this - [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/HN3Ba/14/)

On button click, we set the `display` attribute of our fieldset to `none`, so it's not displayed.

Comment: he wants it to be closed in rest of the pages if its closed once.

Comment: means if you refrech the page you want see this div again ?

Comment: no no..not see.   When close the pop up then not coming when refresh the page but when user close the browser and open the website then display..